# Implementing a recently used or favorites dropdown in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am looking for code that will add favorites / MRU type behavior to a JComboBox.

I could code this myself, but it sure seems like someone else has probably already done it.

I found the following (which looks exactly like what I want, but the source code is nowhere near complete): http://java.sys-con.com/node/36658

Any suggestions?  I need to keep this relatively light, so I'd prefer to not use a component that's part of a monolithic widget library, and open source is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider extending [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html): override `addElement()` and `insertElementAt()` to insert at zero and remove the last element.

Addendum: Here's an example; per SO, the license is [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/). I'd use [`Preferences`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html) to persist the entries.

```
class MRUComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {

    @Override
    public void addElement(Object element) {
        this.insertElementAt(element, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertElementAt(Object element, int index) {
        super.insertElementAt(element, 0);
        int size = this.getSize();
        if (size > 10) {
            this.removeElementAt(size - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll do for my needs (deciding when to add elements will require a focus change listener, which is easy enough).  The component described in the link in the question is a lot fancier, but your approach is sufficient for what I'm doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about just subclassing `JComboBox` and overriding the

```
public void addItem(Object anObject)
```

to give it the functionality you want?

You can just keep an internal list of items synched with the effective one, and whenever you add a new item it can check if `size() >= maxItems` and trim down least recent ones.

Then you should find a way to refresh an item whenever it is used. If its selection it's enough to be refreshed you can write an `ItemListener` that does it. Otherwise you'll need a specified external action or an observer/observable pattern..